# Can I Test My Core Data Model?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Is there a way I can load a sample object with properties etc into AppDelegate DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  Then I can test all my tableViews etc that everything from core data is loading up fine.  Once it is fine, I can modify the methods to take in user input instead of the preloaded data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://iamleeg.blogspot.com/2010/01/unit-testing-core-data-driven-apps-fit.html) might be what you're looking for in terms of Core Data unit testing approaches.